# The understanding of logic of "construct" method in original STL implementation in C++

Tags: c++, stl, new-operator, copy-constructor, allocator

While going through the [Alexander Stepanov](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Stepanov) original STL(Standard Template Library) source code, I encountered the following from the memory allocator function file: [defalloc.h](http://www.stepanovpapers.com/butler.hpl.hp/stl/stl/DEFALLOC.H)

```
template <class T1, class T2>
inline void construct(T1* p, const T2& value) {
    new (p) T1(value);
}
```

I am not able to understand it completely and have the following question/doubts:

1. It appears to me that it has something to do with copy constructor of type `T1`?
2. Why the above function is template on two type `T1` & `T2`?. It should have been `T1*` for first and `*T1` for second(value).
3. why `new` has been used in the above logic?. I looked the uses of it and found the following in file [vector.h](http://www.stepanovpapers.com/butler.hpl.hp/stl/stl/VECTOR.H)

> ```
> void push_back(const T& x) {
>   if (finish != end_of_storage) {
>       construct(finish, x);
>         ....
>         ....
>     }
> ```

So based on above, finish has already acquired the memory and been passed into it. The other parameter is x which is value of same type T. These are the few concepts which I am able to think/understand.

It appears to me very general yet important function which has been used throughout STL logic. Could somebody can explain it the above concept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a placement `new`, which is a specific kind of `new` where you specify directly the (already allocated) memory to be used for the value to `new`.

> Why the above function is template on two type T1 & T2?

In this case, it is a placement `new` that accepts a value to initialize something of a different type through a cast, as you do when you use a constructor for a class. (Note the cast to `T1` on the `new` statement).

You could, for example construct a `std::string` from a `const char*` **and** with placement `new` in a single, readable, concise function. Here, T1 = `std::string` and T2 = `const char*`.

[**Live example on Coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1256aa3e8a806bc3)